# Would somebody be yotze the Megillah reading by watching it LIVE STREAMING while following from a Kosher Megillah?

Tags: technology, megillat-esther

On motzei shabbat, I usually watch the megillah being read from The Shul of the Seven Beggars on my computer, which, for the record had been turned on, and set up, before Shabbat following their instructions, so as not to transgress the Shabbat. Further, I have a kosher Megillah and follow the reading as well, but I do not know the *trop* and *nekudot* well enough to read on my own.

Theoretically speaking, would listening to a live stream of a megillah reading and following along be considered a true leining?  Would a listener be yotze?  Why or why not? And if not, why do they lein it LIVE streaming on the computer?

The other 3 answers do not really answer my question. I added the word LIVE to the question

MY APOLOGIES if this is a double question, but I can not find anything similarly applicable.

Comment: Does this meet the requirement to reopen?

Comment: I don’t understand what your Megillah has anything to do with the question: if it’s a kosher Megillah, why do you need the livestream? Since you’re reading it, you’re yotzei without anyone else reading it for you. If it’s not a kosher Megillah, it doesn’t help for anything (except maintaining concentration, perhaps). Am I missing something?

Comment: @DonielF I guess he doesn't know the trop, or maybe not even the nekudos, so he wants to hear somebody read it out loud?  (But then youtube is no worse than live stream.)

Comment: @Heshy Isn’t that the question - does the fact that it’s live change anything?

Comment: @DonielF  I have no knowledge of how the tropes sound anymore. The last time I used them was at my Bar Mitzvah, 67 years ago on 22 Elul. My Hebrew and nikodot are not so perfect that I can be really sure I am saying the words correctly. Therefore the live streaming to hear the words correctly said.

Comment: @YeruchamDavidbenMordecai Oh, I missed in your question that you’re asking for practical Halacha. In that case you should ask your Rabbi - none of us are qualified to be your local orthodox Rav.

Comment: @DonielF  With the greatest respect, I have no intention of reacting to HESHY any longer. On my other questioned I felt that he was ridiculing and trying to humiliate me. In this period of Selichot, I apologize to him for these remarks, and hope that he may perhaps reconsider the manner in which he appears, to me, to answer people. L'Shana Tova Tikotavu

Comment: @YeruchamDavidbenMordecai If you really think it’s a problem, maybe you should try to contact one of the mods? I’m sorry that you had these experiences, and I hope it doesn’t color your experience here.

Comment: @DonielF I made no mention of practical Halacha; but in any case, the reason I watch the live streaming and read the Megillah, is because I do not have a regular Kehillah or Orthodox Rabbi. I am an Invalid and can never get to Schul on days when it is forbidden to drive, as the nearest Schule is 58 kilometers away.

Comment: @DonielF I don't want disharmony and bad feelings. I hope that HESHY will simply reconsider his words in the future.    Generally speaking, I very much enjoy my experiences here. And with you, it is very easy to understand what you are asking.  JOELK was also most helpful to me in advising what changes I should make to revalidate the question.  I sincerely believe that most people on Mi Yodea are here with sincere questions, and a desire to learn.  MOST of us do not realise when a question may be a duplicate question. We need guidance. You are a good example of guidance as is JOELK.

Comment: @YeruchamDavidbenMordecai I apologize to you and hope you can forgive me at this time of the year.  And, on the other side, there is nothing at all for you to apologize for.  You've taught me to be more careful with my tone and I thank you for that.  I don't think this is a duplicate or bad question in any way, and while I don't quite understand what you meant in your other question, I don't consider it bad or silly.  May you also be written and sealed for a good year in all ways and have a happy special birthday.

Comment: @YeruchamDavidbenMordecai I feel for you - I really do. You’re not the only one who’s had to miss Megillah reading for being an invalid, though in my case it was Eichah rather than Esther. You’re right to look for other solutions, this just isn’t the place to find them. [Mi Yodeya isn’t a Rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-mi-yodeya). The same way you wouldn’t ask how space ships work here, this isn’t the place to ask for Halachic advice. This is an excellent question, don’t misunderstand - this just isn’t the place to get it answered. I wish you a Refuah Sheleimah u’Meheirah.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that the Megillah doesn’t have to be read in shul. If you can’t make it to shul, is there anyone from shul who can make it to you?

Comment: @DonielF unfortunately not anyone competent. I live 58km and, of course, the Chabad Rabbi can't walk :) that far :)

Comment: Something to consider: It doesn't have to be the minute Shabbat ends.  It could be any time during the night.   So if your health allows it and someone is willing, he could drive to you and read it a little later that night.

Comment: I'd also like to ask your forgiveness a second time if you're willing to grant it.   I will be much more careful with my tone in the future.

Comment: Forgiven gladly...  and tank you for the suggestion. SHAKE HANDS

Comment: What megilla are you asking about?

Comment: This question was asked a year and a half before COVID, but it seems especially salient now, in February 2021.