# Reading along in a kosher megillah - impediment to others?

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, megillat-esther, hearing

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [141:15](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4297986/jewish/Chapter-141-Laws-Concerning-the-Reading-of-the-Megillah.htm#v15) says you should not read along in the Megillah if you don't have a kosher scroll, because even if you can simultaneously concentrate on the public reading, people nearby might inadvertently listen to you instead of the reader:

> מִי שֶׁיֵשׁ לְפָנָיו מְגִלָּה פְסוּלָה אוֹ חֻמָּשׁ, לֹא יִקְרָא עִם
> שְּׁלִיחַ הַצִבּוּר. כִּי אִם הוּא קוֹרֵא, אֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְכַוֵּן
> לִשְׁמֹעַ מִן שְּׁלִיחַ הַצִבּוּר. וַאֲפִלוּ אִם הוּא יְכַוֵּן,
> שֶׁמָּא יִשְׁמַע אַחֵר מַה שֶׁהוּא קוֹרֵא, וְלֹא יְכַוֵן לִקְרִיאַת
> שְּׁלִיחַ הַצִּבּוּר

But in halacha [13](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4297986/jewish/Chapter-141-Laws-Concerning-the-Reading-of-the-Megillah.htm#v13), we learn that the reader must have in mind to fulfill the obligation of all the listeners, and vice versa:

> הַקוֹרֵא אֶת הַמְּגִלָּה, צָרִיךְ לְכַוֵּן לְהוֹצִיא אֶת כָּל
> הַשּׁוֹמְעִים. וְגַם הַשּׁוֹמֵעַ צָרִיךְ לְכַוֵּן לָצֵאת

If so, wouldn't it be problematic to read aloud even from a kosher scroll? Presumably you don't have the other congregants in mind, and they don't intend to listen to you, so anyone overhearing your reading would fail to fulfill the mitzvah.

I suppose this could be one reason it's best to [read along silently](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120549/6592), but in that case why tie the issue to the lack of a kosher scoll?

Comment: You could just have everyone in mind, problem solved

Comment: @DoubleAA half the problem solved

Comment: @Rabbi you're worried the guy listening isn't trying to fulfill his obligation???

Comment: I.e. a) 13 doesn't specify that they have to hear or be yotze by _him_, just hear the Megilla and concentrate on being yotze. 15 wouldn't make sense if one also couldn't read from a kosher Megilla along with the public reading

Comment: @Rabb I don't understand your comment